# Unable to Fetch a 40MB JSON file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, velo

I have a Wix website with JavaScript and I want to import a big (40MB) JSON file.

The `getJsonProducts` function is working with smaller files but not with a file of this size.

```
export async function getJsonProducts() {
    console.log("fetching");
     await getJSON("link")
        .then(json => {
            console.log(json.root.item[1]);
            console.log("end");
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

I get a Timeout error:

```
elementory-browser-support.min.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) ExecutionTimeoutError: WebMethod request timed-out after 14 seconds... Did you forget to resolve a promise?
    at FunctionErrorsProvider.getTimeoutError (node_modules/@wix/cloud-runtime-core/lib/providers/FunctionErrorsProvider.js:18:19)
    at timeout.catch.err (node_modules/@wix/cloud-runtime-core/lib/processors/FunctionExecutor.js:20:46)
    at bound (domain.js:396:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:409:12)
    at tryCatcher (node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:26:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:510:31)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:584:18)
    at Promise._settlePromises (node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:700:14)
    at Async._drainQueue (node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:123:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:133:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:15:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
    at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:121:23)
```

Comment: Have you tried looking into the network tab in the browser developer tools to see if the request is being made and also when it completes what the response is? See: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/

Comment: You should never try to load everything (here I mean with huge JSON files) with one request/response. Your approach is not right. You should do multiple calls to fetch a smaller part of data and load in the application, rather than fetching everything at once.

Comment: @TameemSafi added the error message from the developer tools

Comment: @user10128333 I didnt found a option to fetch the json in pieces

Comment: You should use pagination .... The file is too big, try finding a way to reduce it, either via pagination, either send less data in it.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant I never done it befor, it is just to split the json in more files and but the links of the other files also into the json?

Comment: random example https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/01/31/angularjs-pagination-example-with-logic-like-google . The idea is to let the user access only a part of the whole list, with minimal content in it. If you want to access a specific product, you should do a GET request to get the whole data about that product, not the others.

Comment: I am not sure about your endpoints, but the idea was to use pagination to send smaller chunk of data as JSON response.